# Android, GUI design w/ Eclipse, Layout->View->Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I'm trying to find my way into Android development. I'm using Eclipse Helios. The GUI design software seems to make it impossible to design certain element hierarchies. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="110px">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="30px"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have not been able to design this structure in the GUI designer. I drag a LinearLayout to the design frame, drag a ScrollView over it, then drag a LinearLayout on top. Always, this will be inserted as a child of the first LinearLayout, not of the ScrollView. However, in [this example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example/) for ScrollViews, this seems to be right.

Am I doing something wrong? How would I design this structure using the GUI designer? Or is this only possible by direct XML manipulation?

Thanks.

Comment: The GUI designer simply isn't very good. Getting used to doing it in xml will help you in other areas of your app too. I think they may be releasing a much better version of the designer in 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wysiwyg editor for android is badly broken.

They just released one in the new sdk version and from their own saying : "It is a complete rewrite and is far from really usable but this new version is on par with the old one so we released it"

Use the Wysiwyg up to where you can't get it to do what you want then switch to xml is the best advice I can give you.

Most senior developers don't even trust wysiwyg in the first place and would advise you to just go xml...You write what you want and get it the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, Yahel, that is interesting information. Could you link me the release where this is documented? I was already pretty certain that direct XML manipulation was the way to go, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you want to drag new elements and make them children of specific ViewGroups, I find it helpful to drag to the outline window instead of the main window.  Lets you get pretty specific without having to start in the xml.

(I know this is an old question, but thought the response might be helpful)